# QuerySelectorAll not working when put in an external js file

Tags: javascript, onload, onload-event, selectors-api

When I put this code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
    console.log(inputs.length);
    for(var j=0; j<inputs.length; j++){
        inputs[j].onclick = function(){
            this.style.width = "500px";
        }
    }
}
```

Into an html page, it works great, but if I put it into an external .js file the for loop never starts as inputs.length is equal to 0, even if in the page that calls the script there are plenty of inputs. What could be the problem?

**Update**:
I found out that the code works in normal conditions, but it doesn't:

- <s>on inputs that are contained in a div that was previously hidden and
  then was shown via js</s> my bad, the hidden input was of type "email"
- <s>on every input if they're loaded via ajax</s> I found out why: since the function is fired only when the window loads, it won't see the loaded inputs

Comment: I'm guessing `window.onload` is called elsewhere, overwriting the callback, but who knows ?

Comment: @adeneo But if the callback were overwritten, the callback would not be called at all, including the `console.log` which the OP says is showing 0.

Comment: Is there any text field exists in DOM before this script is executing. Just use debugger to find it.

Comment: "_which the OP says is showing 0_"   Well that's not what he said, maybe he just deduced it was equal to 0 since the loop doesn't start.

Comment: @lleaff no it's console.log(inputs.length) that outputs 0

Comment: @JitendraKhatri there are plenty of inputs in the dom when it is loaded

Comment: this i gotta see; got a fiddle for us?

Comment: This shouldn't matter but try putting the `<script>` at the very bottom of your `<body>` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Stubborn  are inputs of type text

Comment: This is weird... I've just created a basic page with just some text and a text input [here](http://en.stubborn.altervista.org/req/test.php) and it works, when I put it in my application it doesn't

Comment: @lleaff it doesn't work anyway in my application

Comment: ah there you go ,`querySelectorAll()` doesn't return a live collection ,so dynamically added content won't be reflected in the results

Comment: @Ramanlfc that explains why it doesn't work on ajax loaded content; I found out that the hidden input was of type "email" and not "text". Gosh, feel free to insult me for my dumbness. Thank you all for your help

Comment: if something sounds too good (or bad) to be true, it's probably a typo...

Comment: @dandavis nothing truer than that hahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the users who commented/answered, I found out that some of the inputs I was trying the code to were of type "email" and not "text", while in other cases the inputs were loaded via ajax, so after the DOM was loaded. To fix these problems, I've edited

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
```

To

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text],input[type=email]");
```

And I called again the function when the content loaded via ajax was ready.

Answer (score 8):

Very often, the placement of your script tag can affect your DOM selection. So make sure that your script tag is placed at the bottom of your html file just before the end of the body tag. Perhaps this will fix the issue!

Comment: Such a simple answer, but to a newbie, this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching your function with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of setting `window.onload`:

```
window.addEventListener(function() {
    //...
});
```

If this solves your problem then as @adeneo said, window.onload is being assigned elsewhere in the script which overwrites any other value it can have.
Which is why in general, using `addEventListener` is better as you can call it as many times as you want without overwriting anything.

But the problem could also simply be that your script isn't being evaluated at all, did you try putting some top-level `console.log` in there?

Comment: Unfortunately, using addEventListener doesn't work anyway. I've got some other code in the same external file which is being executed